# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-03-28 11:16:38"

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, dao

I am trying to store in "2015-03-28 11:16:38" into my database from user input on a jsp.
but im getting this error

> "java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-03-28 11:16:38"

```
String xDate = request.getParameter("timeRequested");
Date newDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US).parse(xDate);
timeRequested = newDate;
```

Comment: Funny enough i just realised that when i posted it. Thank you very much

Comment: I can't reproduce this... although I would strongly recommend specifying a time zone in the `SimpleDateFormat`. Please provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, double check if the space you have in `2015-03-28 11:16:38` is really a single space and not a '\t' or the like